# changing file permission ownership

Tags: linux, permissions, ssh, sftp

Here are my file permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1556 Mar 18 01:31 search.php
```

I keep try to edit it in winscp and its telling me:

Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission denied
Request code: 3

How do I change this so I can edit this through winscp?

Comment: Please clarify. winscp is a copy program. How do you edit it with a copy program? Are you editing it on remote machine? Local machine? What user to you authenticate with?

Comment: Its with an amazon server, in SSH under root I can edit the file fine. ..but when I login with winscp I can open the file nor overwrite. basically I am asking what user should own the file which will allow me to use winscp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the owner of the file to be the same as whatever user you log in as when you run winscp. For example:

```
chown user1179295:user1179295 search.php
```

The name after the colon is the group name, which is probably either `users` or the same as your user name. You can do an `ls` in your home directory to see what your user and group names are.